# Access .NET dll's method using Java code

Tags: java, .net

I have a dll namely `product.dll` created using .NET. How can I access that dll's constructor or method using Java code.
Is it possible to access without using JNI?

Comment: This is funny, the converse question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895445/calling-a-java-api-from-net-best-approach) was asked less than four minutes later (by someone else). Funny old world.

Answer (score 6):

You may take a look at [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) which allows interoperability between the two. [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/) is another alternative. Yet another option is to expose the functionality you have in the .NET library as a SOAP web service which is interoperable and could be consumed from a JAVA client.

Comment: IKVM.NET seems to be for accessing Java from .NET, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

There is a commercial product called JNBridgePro that will allow you to easily do this.  You can even run the .NET dll inside the Java process if you like.  (You can also run the Java and .NET in separate processes and communicate through sockets.)  For more information, please see www.jnbridge.com, or contact us at the e-mail address on the Web site.  (Yes, I am with JNBridge, but I felt that mentioning the product was appropriate in these circumstances.)