# Calling a Java API from .NET - best approach

Tags: c#, java, .net, java-native-interface

I need to call an API that's all in java from an existing .NET codebase. What's the best approach here? Writing a webservice in java that basically just forwards the calls to the API - or going with something like [JNI4NET](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: This is funny, the converse question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895434/access-net-dlls-method-using-java-code) was asked less than four minutes earlier (by someone else). Funny old world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/), which is a JNI bridge between .Net and Java. (Props to Darin Dimitrov for [providing this info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895434/access-net-dlls-method-using-java-code/2895453#2895453) in an answer to another question.)

Comment: I wish I could give Darin Dimitrov the answer, but I'll have to give it to you instead :) I ended up going with IKVM for the task, and after alot of work I got it working like a charm!

Comment: @Ciddan: Yeah. I even posted a link to this question in the one I lifted the info from, but he didn't bite. :-) Have to settle for us both upvoting him, eh?

Answer (score 1):

That depends. If it is a desktop application, you can use JNI. But for a web based application you have to use the web services.

Comment: The usecase is that I'm going to be calling into the java api from a WAS-hosted WCF service. Does that preclude the JNI approach?

Comment: You can use JNI in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If its a web based application you can also look at using an RMI proxy object on the java server side and [IIOP.NET](http://iiop-net.sourceforge.net/rmiAdderDNClient.html) on the .NET client side.

It will be orders of magnitude faster than web services.