# How to Load .net (VB) dll and use method in It in java

Tags: java, vb.net, dll

I have a .net dll which has some functions that i need to call from a java program.
This is the code that I have used which is giving me this error."Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:" but the dll loads fine.
    s

```
static {
        try {

            System.load("mydotnet.dll");
            System.out.println("loaded");

        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            System.err.println(e);

        }
    }

    private static native boolean SC_Start();
```

Comment: What do you mean "dll loads fine"?

Comment: the dll load well but accessing the function in the dll is giving this errror:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Comment: How `SC_Start` method declared in VBNet?

Comment: Anyway you cant just use Net dll. Java works with native dll's only. You need to wrap you Net dll into native one.

Comment: Do you have any idea/code to achieve this?

Comment: You can try this for start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283679/how-can-i-call-net-code-from-java

Answer (score 0):

Is your DLL in a directory on the Java PATH?

If not, either:

1. Add the directory containing the DLL to the PATH
2. Move the DLL to a directory already in the PATH
3. Or use the full path to the DLL, eg C:\Path\To\Directory\mydotnet.dll

Comment: the dll load well but accessing the function in the dll is giving this errror:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Comment: Is your DLL set up to be used by Java?

Java can't just load and use any old .NET DLL

See this answer for an explanation
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675179/accessing-dll-methods-in-java