# Considerations for writing .net code to be used in Java

Tags: java, .net, interop

I'm creating a touch screen that is going to be used by a POS system written in Java.  I'm a .net developer and I understand that .net assemblies can be consumed by Java, but I am not aware if there are any considerations I need to make on my end so that the assembly can be used.

For example, when I wrote .net dll's for use in VB6 in the past I had to expose methods to COM.  Does Java interoperate with .net assemblies through COM or can it use them directly (or something else...)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895434/access-net-dlls-method-using-java-code

Comment: Check out the JNI documentation.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not really looking to actually write java code that uses .net dlls myself so while learning how to do so would certainly give me the answer I'm looking for, I'm really just hoping to find out whether I can write code normally on my end and just assume that it will be usable by java.